# Sorting data monthwise in my table

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

I am trying to sort data as per month but the problem is that date in int.
I want to sort data for particular month, but I am not able to convert and solve as per date wise or monthwise.

Please anyone can help me on this.

In my database date is time stamp format like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: if i get link  for reference its also fine

Comment: u can use joda time library http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Simply use `ORDER BY Your_Date_Field` in your queries. The TimeString format is enough to sort by year, month, day, hour, minute and second.

Comment: try it `SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY (select month(yourdateTimeField)) ASC;`

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: sir i have spinner using spinner i select the month like jan,feb ... so using these value i want sort data from my db time format  is same as i mentioned above

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select the dates for a specific year and month? This is far different from what you actually asked.

Comment: i want to select date, month and year and then sort the data

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.sort method in list , If you want take data from database then you use ORDER BY date